# Why is the majority of documentation for ElasticSearch in curl?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm just curious because there isn't a lot of documentation for other API's like Java.

Do most companies and people who use elastic search purely use it through curl? It seems a bit cumbersome to use it in that manner.

Answer (score 2):

Using curl is probably the closest thing to writing the documentation in a language that everyone understands. Regardless of the language, everything speaks the HTTP protocol underneath.

If they wrote the documentation in Ruby/Python/Java, whoever they left out might be unhappy. So by using curl, a tool which all web developers learn eventually, they are writing the documentation in a language-agnostic way.